# creating blank field and receving the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY with sqlite, python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using sqlite with python. When i insert into table A i need to feed it an ID from table B. So what i wanted to do is insert default data into B, grab the id (which is auto increment) and use it in table A. Whats the best way receive the key from the table i just inserted into?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Christian said, `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()` is what you want... but that's the C level API, and you're using the Python DB-API bindings for SQLite.

It looks like the cursor method `lastrowid` will do what you want [(search for 'lastrowid' in the documentation for more information)](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html). Insert your row with `cursor.execute( ... )`, then do something like `lastid = cursor.lastrowid` to check the last ID inserted.

That you say you need "an" ID worries me, though... it doesn't matter *which* ID you have? Unless you are using the data just inserted into B for something, in which case you need *that* row ID, your database structure is seriously screwed up if you just need any old row ID for table B.

Comment: One thing which could probably be more clear -- lastrowid gives you the row ID, *not* the autoincrementing primary key; an extra query should be run to retrieve that key.

Comment: Actually, that last objection I had was wrong; see http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: Yeah, SQLite is a quirky little database... it's edge cases like this that really make me appreciate features like `INSERT... RETURNING` in Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) -- it's probably what you're looking for:

> Each entry in an SQLite table has a
>   unique 64-bit signed integer key
>   called the "rowid". The rowid is
>   always available as an undeclared
>   column named ROWID, OID, or _ROWID_ as
>   long as those names are not also used
>   by explicitly declared columns. If the
>   table has a column of type INTEGER
>   PRIMARY KEY then that column is
>   another alias for the rowid.
>
> This routine returns the rowid of the
>   most recent successful INSERT into the
>   database from the database connection
>   in the first argument. If no
>   successful INSERTs have ever occurred
>   on that database connection, zero is
>   returned.

Hope it helps!  (More info on ROWID is available [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) and [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html).)

Comment: That will certainly work with APSW, but I'm not sure that the DB-API compliant Python module (pysqlite) provides access to that call.

Comment: In Python it looks like it's wrapped by cursor.lastrowid, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid();
```

However, if you have multiple connections writing to the database, you might not get back the key that you expect.